# Допустимость слишком общих ответов

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, удаление-ответов

Хотел бы поинтересоваться мнением сообщества (и, в частности, его администрации) относительно того, допускаются ли ответы, которые чисто технически являются ответами на вопрос, но столь общие, что никак не могут помочь ни автору вопроса, ни человеку, который столкнётся с подобной проблемой / задачей.

Пример такого вопроса [в теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116955/361777) / [в очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/469774)
Технически это ответ на вопрос, но он настолько очевидный, что буквально взят из тела самого вопроса.

Стоит ли флагать такие ответы / рекомендовать их удаление, или же достаточно просто поставить `-1`? Если стоит, то с применением какого пункта?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Здесь нет смысла давать ответ или выяснять правильные ли даны ответы, потому что вопрос вида "Нужна помощь в работе со строками в Python3" сам по себе является бесполезным.  Необходимо переформулировать вопрос либо закрыть.

Переформулировать вопрос должен сам автор, потому что непонятно, какого плана ответы его интересуют:

- на вопрос "как вывести массив строк на питоне" будут одни ответы
- на вопрос "почему этот код вызвал такую ошибку" будут другие ответы, при
  чем в этом случае правильнее было бы еще уточнить, зачем такой код.

В любом случае, если автор последует [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), то скорее всего он сам закроет свой вопрос в итоге.

> Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили.

Comment: *`"...убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа..."`* -- очевидное лукавство. Согласитесь, если бы все **действительно тщательно** искали ответ на вопросы (по крайней мере на те, что в рамках правил), то никого из отвечающих тут просто бы не было

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что в интернете есть ответы на все вопросы на несколько лет вперед? :-)

Comment: @avp, кстати два примера: 1) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753216. Искал тщательно, но не в том направлении. 2) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796393. Искал тщательно, но не "действительно тщательно". В итоге устал и написал вопрос. А потом собрался с силами и нашел ответ.

Comment: Конечно есть ответы, может и не явные, но есть. Только для их извлечения, скажем, из сорсов может понадобится ооооченннннь много времени. Поэтому я всегда говорю, настоящая ценность этого сайта (была?) в том, чтобы можно быстро задать любой вопрос и обсудить его с коллегами, а не искать ответ на него самому

Answer (score 6):

Такие ответы допустимы, конечно. Но только до тех пор, пока на него не поставят тревогу (¬‿¬ )

Я такие ответы переношу по тревогам в комментарии, т.к. они ничего нового не привносят в обсуждение вопроса.

Порой замечаю такое за людьми с большой репутацией, которые подобными ответами пытаются показать, что вопрос (якобы) плохой. Работает такое плохо и может оскорбить участника.

Если бы в ответе были бы какие-то пояснения (как в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116980/15479)), то всё было бы нормально.

> Стоит ли флагать такие ответы / рекомендовать их удаление, или же достаточно просто поставить -1? Если стоит, то с применением какого пункта?

Да, пункт "не является ответом".

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, вполне нормальный ответ.

Comment: Почему Вы так считаете? Пожалуйста, раскройте немного мысль.

Comment: Это нормальный ответ только в парадигме "ССЗБ: как вы задали -- так вам и надо", чтобы на каждый, даже плохо сформированный вопрос был хоть какой-нибудь ответ. Минусуют очевидно сторонники точки зрения "плохо сформулированные вопросы не нужно пытаться отвечать - их нужно закрывать и требовать прояснить".

Comment: По-моему тоже .

Comment: tl;dr Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.  / 

Если говорить о конкретно об этом ответе, то я тоже считаю его нормальным. В данном случае проблема в вопросе. Лично я стараюсь такие "ответы" давать в комментариях, ибо они несут пользу только тому, кто задал вопрос, а всем остальным (тем, кто найдет вопрос через гугл) пользы 0.

Comment: @RTK `Какой вопрос, такой и ответ`. Это не так работает...

Comment: @AK я бы поставил минус, т.к. это не ответ, а комментарий, причём бесполезный.

Comment: Может, параноик, но глядя на голоса чувствую рождение новой проблемы этого сообщества --- скоро любой ответ без разжёвывания будет удаляться и минусоваться.

Answer (score 2):

**Вопрос:**

*`:before` - это псевдоэлемент, который применяется для отображения желаемого контента до содержимого элемента, к которому он добавляется?*

**Ответ:**

*Да.*

---

**Из этого следует вопрос:**

Ответ `Да` не является ответом?

Comment: <ирония>Нет, хорошим ответом будет - 
`Да, это псевдоэлемент, который применяется для отображения желаемого контента до содержимого элемента.`
</ирония>

Comment: Я к тому и писал ниже, что на "плохой" вопрос сложно дать хороший ответ.